# Semicolon in R ODBC connection password

Tags: sql, r, passwords, odbc

When using RGui(64-bit), the following steps yield a prompt that will let me connect to my ODBC.

```
library(RODBC)

odbc_sample = odbcConnect("SAMPLE", uid="user_sample", pwd="sam;ple")
```

I am then told "Connect Failed" (this is because there is a semicolon in the password) and a pop up comes up called "SQL Server Login". It says Data Source: SAMPLE Login ID: user_sample Password: ....

I then enter my password `sam;ple` and the connection goes through just fine.

When I'm in R Studio, I run the same line of code for odbc_sample = and all I get is "Connection Failed". The pop up to enter the password never comes up. I also tried several methods to deal with the semicolon in the password.

Comment: It seems *SAMPLE* is a DSN. Consider putting user and password inside this connection file.

Comment: Thanks! what do you mean by "inside this connection file"? Is there a DSN line of code?

Comment: *Sample* is likely a pre-built [DSN (Data Source Name)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879308(v=sql.105).aspx) which are config files that retains connection details. Do you recall creating this? Check your odbcad32.exe under System32 or SysWOW64.

Comment: Understand...Yes, I did create it myself. It is USER DSN, under SQL Server DSN. I selected 'With SQL Server authentication using a login ID and password entered by the user.' I then type the Login ID and Password, continue through the prompts and it says 'Test Connection Successful'. However, with this being said... when I try odbcConnect ("SAMPLE") it says it cannot connect. The only way I can connect is if I used the code above in RGui and after it fails it prompts me for the username and password. I need a way to connect in R Studio. Hope this clarifies my issue.

Comment: Also, when I'm in RStudio.... if I go through the Connections prompts when selected 'New Connection', I test the connection and it is also succesful. When I selected ok and the code runs, it says "error failed for user 'user_sample'. For some reason the actual code execution has issues with the semicolon. In RGui when this fails, a prompt appears for me to enter username and password. In RStudio when this fails, no prompt appears and it just says ODBC connection failed. I need a way past this part in RStudio.

Comment: *when I try odbcConnect ("SAMPLE") it says it cannot connect.* ... please relay the exact error message. And make sure your [SQL Server services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/start-stop-pause-resume-restart-sql-server-services). Check under [Task Manager\Services](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/sites/default/files/gdrive/task_mgr_services/task_manager_1.jpg).